# AngularJS - Grunt: Does a solution exist to build a running application with only desired modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, module, gruntjs

I'm currenlty doing the refactoring of an application and I want to follow the John Papa's guidelines as I found them very interesting and usefull in my case: [John Papa Guidelines - Application Structure](http://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#application-structure-lift-principle)

So I arrive at the part where I decided to split my application into different modules corresponding to the features. Let's say one module for the accounts feature, one for the transfer feature and one for the user settings feature.

I can do it well according to the John Papa recommendations: one app module and three other modules (account-module.js, transfer-module.js and user-settings-module.js) and their corresponding navigation (states-config.js, etc.).

I hope I have been enough clear because now the tricky part comes :D

The idea I have is that I would like to build two (or more) different applications depending on what I want. I would like for example to build an application without the transfer module and doing this during my grunt process (by configuration).

Currently I am using the include_source grunt and grunt_war later on but there is no way to be more in an "angular module" context rather than using regular expression to specify which files I would like.
Those tasks don't allow us to say like "Okay, I would like to package this, this, and this module" for example (that would be fantastic!)

I think that big applications should have encountered this problematic as when they don't provide all business modules to every customer but make it configurable (at least I hope that's how they do).

The question is how? Do they do it? Is it manually (non sense), or do they have written some custom grunt (gulp) task or some custom scripts for this purpose?

---

Bonus question: Let's imagine we are living in a dream world and a grunt task exist for this. My next question will be, how to manage it within my application to configure my navigation for example (no more transfer button in the menu). I think that if the grunt task and the app use the same configuration file, that won't be a problem and I will be able to use grunt-angular-settings task to have a constant within my app.

Thanks for your attention and I'm very curious to read you :)

Regards, Yassine GAYL

Answer (score 0):

interesting. take a look at how `angular.js` itself builds the artifacts. in src code, it has bunch of modules scattered in different folders. it introduces `lib/grunt/utils` and `lib/grunt/plugins` to handle the build process, say which modules should go into which destination file. you might have interests to try the same, good luck with it.

---

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L166

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at how Angular libraries are managed and how the build is done thanks to your link. I think I will probably do smomething similar but I would like to make it more general. How it is done within this gruntfile is very specific to it. It's recommended to use angularjs modules so I was surprise to not find something allowing to make this.